# Is there a webmail client which can handle mutiple mail accounts?

Tags: email, web, web-application

Everyone here must be aware of mail clients which can handle multiple email accounts simultaneously(eg. Thunderbird or Outlook). These are desktop clients which should my installed on the clients computer.Suppose i don't have harddisk, now how will  i access my multiple mail accounts on web using a single application ?

Thanks in advance,
Tanmoy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail is a webmail that supports accessing multiple accounts via POP and IMAP.

To access this, on the top left hand side click the `Settings` link.  Then select the `Accounts and Import` category.

Answer (score 4):

If Gmail cannot be used, [RoundCube](http://roundcube.net/) webmail has an addon that allows acces to sever different IMAP accounts. This solution requires a local web server but no install on the client.

Comment: Awesome! Could you point to a link to the plugin which allows this?

Comment: There's [a trac discussion](http://trac.roundcube.net/ticket/1484075) that indicates that core functionality like this may be considered, but the only solution I've seen provides [IMAP settings per identity](https://myroundcube.com/myroundcube-plugins/identities_imap-plugin).  Perhaps that will do what you need.  Please let us know your results.